# get written text in HTML input field in JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, text

I have the following code in html for a simple form

```
<main>
  <form role="form">
    <fieldset id="personal-information" name="personal-information">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>

      <section class="usernameSection" name="first-name">
        <label for="username">username:*</label>
        <input
          id="username"
          type="text"
          name="textfield"
          placeholder="username"
        />
      </section>
      <br />
      <section class="passwordSection" name="passwordSection">
        <label for="password">password:*</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
        />
      </section>
      <section class="submit" name="sumbit">
        <button id="submitButton" type='button' name="submit button"/>Sign in</button>
      </section>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

and in js I have the following code:

```
function signIn(userName, password) {
  console.log(userName,password)
}

const currentUsername = document.getElementById("username");
const currentPassword = document.getElementById("password");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  signIn(currentUsername.innerText, currentPassword.innerText);
});
```

The idea is just to log the username and passsword the users put in this field, but whenever I do this the console prints `"" ""`

Am I getting the input incorrectly by using .innerText?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `value` rather than `innerText` because you're working with form elements.    `signIn(currentUsername.value, currentPassword.value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.value` instead of `.innerText`.

```js
function signIn(userName, password) {
  console.log(userName,password)
}

const currentUsername = document.getElementById("username");
const currentPassword = document.getElementById("password");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  signIn(currentUsername.value, currentPassword.value);
});
```

```html
<main>
  <form role="form">
    <fieldset id="personal-information" name="personal-information">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>

      <section class="usernameSection" name="first-name">
        <label for="username">username:*</label>
        <input
          id="username"
          type="text"
          name="textfield"
          placeholder="username"
        />
      </section>
      <br />
      <section class="passwordSection" name="passwordSection">
        <label for="password">password:*</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
        />
      </section>
      <section class="submit" name="sumbit">
        <button id="submitButton" type='button' name="submit button"/>Sign in</button>
      </section>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```